# Problems Installing Latex software

Tags: installing, software

The reason that people are experiencing problems installing some latex software might be because it may not compatible with their systems. The MikTeX version I tried to install on my system is (basic-miktex-2.9.6643-x64.exe). This appears to be designed for a 64 bit system. My computer is a 32 bit system. If this is the case, please make available 32 bit LaTeX software. Thank you.

Comment: If you look at the installer name `*-x64.exe` means that it is built for 64 bit OS. The 32 bit installers won't have such a suffix.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been asked and answered. See this link:

https://miktex.org/download#all

EDIT: I cannot blame the OP for asking. When I did an Internet search for MikTeX 32 bit, most of the responses concerned long-ago issues, feature requests, and other unhelpful matters. On the MikTeX main download page, the link to non-64 bit downloads is very obscure.